# Ubuntu cannot launch intellij anymore

Tags: launcher, intellij

After using intellij for multiple years on the same pc without any problem, suddenly this happened. When I want to startup my intellij on Ubuntu I get an error: "IDE Already Running", Cannot connect to already running IDE instance. CannotActivateException: Process 2 is still running. When I press "V ok" intellij starts up, opens, and then closes immediatly. I've tried restarting my pc and reinstalling intellij. When I check my running processes, nothing that has anything to do with intelijj is running.

After trying to do some root-cause analysis I am pretty sure it is an ubuntu problem, not an intellij problem. But I cannot seem to figure out what this process 2 is, nor where it is running.

Comment: I launch it from the GUI, It has been installed from the software center from ubuntu

Comment: And the version of Ubuntu is??

Comment: The version is 20.04.5 LTS

Answer (score 6):

IntelliJ was running when my laptop was shut down improperly. I had then the same issue.

I solved it by removing the `.lock` file:

```
rm ~/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.2/.lock
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the error happened. But I removed the GUI-installed intellij again and then I installed using the terminal. Afterwards I ran with the terminal and I launched. So it has to do something with the ubuntu software center.

for people like me that don't just know all the commands:

install:

```
sudo snap install intellij-idea-community --classic
```

launch:

```
intellij-idea-community
```

Answer (score 0):

My installation of IDEA was done through software center. That installs it as a snap. And this got me back in:

```
sudo snap revert intellij-idea-community
# Tried opening here still failed with older version
sudo snap refresh intellij-idea-community
# Works now!
```